# C# Regex trying to understand the logic

Tags: regex

I'm starving to understand the logic of regex let's say I got this string

1 SM-TEST S/M-BLEU, 25.00 EA 96.00

```
  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     var test = ReadPdfFile("C:\\Users\\mducharme\\Desktop\\PO # 70882.pdf");
     var result = Regex.Split(test, "\r\n|\r|\n");
     foreach (var lines in result)
     {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(lines, @"^\d\s"))
        {
           string line = lines.ToString();
           string pattern = @"^(\S+\s+\S+).*?,(?=\s*\d+\.\d+\b)";
           string replacement = "$1";
           string result2 = Regex.Replace(line, pattern, replacement);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result2);
        }

     }
  }
```

Each lines show a different value like the first one and so on

2 SM-BLABLA S-M-YELLOW, 50.00 EA 96.00...

In the end I want to show up in my MessageBox for the first value only
1 SM-TEST 25.00 EA 96.00
but the regex doesn't seems to do it's job compared to regex101 website code.

Thank you,

Comment: `[\d]*\s` simply matches zero or more digits and a whitespace. I suspect you want `Regex.Replace(text, @"^(\S+\s+\S+)\s.*?(?=,\s*\d)", "$1")`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/GZf9wp/1). That is, remove a part of string between the second word and the next `,` that is folllowed with whitespaces and then a digit.

Comment: Hi yes kind of but there are multiple "," in the string it has to be  the last one before the 25.00

Comment: Do you mean `@"^(\S+\s+\S+)\s.*(?=,\s*\d)"`? Or `@"^(\S+\s+\S+)\s.*(?=,\s*25\.00)"`? Is the number a fixed value that is a "given"? Can you provide an expected output?

Comment: The result I am trying to get is this 1 SM-TEST 25.00 EA 96.00 in other word i want everything between second string and the number 25.00 removed.

Comment: So, `Regex.Replace(text, @"^(\S+\s+\S+).*?(?=\b25\.00\b)", "$1 ")`?

Comment: Tried this ^(\S+\s+\S+).*?(?=\d+.\d+\b) it remove everything from the start not only the middle

Comment: So, `25.00` is not a fixed value. Try `Regex.Replace(text, @"^(\S+\s+\S+).*?,(?=\s*\d+\.\d+\b)", "$1")`. Please pay attention to the replacement, it is `$1`. See https://regex101.com/r/GZf9wp/2

Comment: MessageBox.Show(Regex.Replace(lines, @"^(\S+\s+\S+).*?,(?=\s*\d+\.\d+\b)", "$1")); 
I doesn't seems to remove anything

Comment: If `lines` is a `string` value, then yes, it is what I suggested, and it [works](https://regex101.com/r/GZf9wp/2). You need to add your current relevant code to the question body.

Comment: Yeah on the regex101 it works but in the code it doesn't it return the whole string still oh well :S Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: That means you failed to describe the exact data you have, please an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question is not answerable as it is now. You have to explain what your `lines` is at least.

Comment: updated the body

Comment: See https://ideone.com/hdWCp4

Comment: So, does it work now?

Comment: somehow the result I get is

1 SM-00441 ROOF LATCH BRACKET, TLB, FLAT 25.00 EA 3.84000

Comment: Please. Add the *real* input to the *question body*. Without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is not possible to help you. Do you realize it makes no sense when you say "my input is `1 SM-TEST S/M-BLEU, 25.00 EA 96.00`", and then say "my output is <a string that is X times longer>"?

Comment: yes that was an example that I gave at start the real line is
SM-00441 ROOF LATCH BRACKET, TLB, FLAT 25.00 EA 3.84000

Comment: And what is the expected output? When you provide a sample string, it must always be accompanied with the expected output. `string pattern = @"^(\S+\s+\S+).*?,[^,\d]*(?=\d+\.\d+\b)";`? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/5VC5Zc).

Comment: 1 SM-00441 25.00 EA 3.84000

Comment: with the last pattern you almost got it the only problem is the multiple "," in that text

Comment: See https://ideone.com/5VC5Zc, output is `SM-00441 ROOF 25.00 EA 3.84000`, where are the commans?

Comment: It should remove anything without using the commas until it reach the number

Comment: I think `string line = lines.ToString();` is redundant, `lines` is a string. Use `foreach (var line in result)`. You can really use something like `string result2 = Regex.Replace(line, @"^(\S+\s+\S+).*?(?=\d+\.\d+\b)", "$1 ");`. If you need to only show the first line results, you just need `break` in the `if` block to break out of the loop upon finding the first line starting with a digit and whitespace.

Comment: ok thank you for your help :) appreciated

Comment: And I still do not know what exactly is appreciated :( What can I put as an answer? `string result2 = Regex.Replace(line, @"^(\S+\s+\S+).*?(?=\d+\.\d+\b)", "$1 ");`???

Comment: Yeah I know it's not very simple I still got error some text are numbers with dot too oh well 9 SM-KB5SSDRT48.52 X 15.03, 7GA 25.00 EA 14.92000

Comment: managed to fix all the problem with two pattern used (\d+.\d+)\s+[xX]\s+(\d+.\d+) to remove the 00.00 X 00.00 then used your pattern and it works perfectly wonder if there's a way to mix both pattern into one. the result it give me is 9 SM-KB5SSDRT 25.00 EA 14.92000 which is perfect.

Comment: Please post several example strings and the expected output of each. Make sure you include some of the more unusual examples... the ones that are giving you problems. Right now you have 1 (?) example but it's not clear how you determine what part of the string you want. Be detailed and clear.

Comment: Also, post a link to your regex101.com example because I'm using your regex and your example and it isn't giving the output you say it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```cs
^(\d+\s+(?:(?!\d+\.\d+\s+[xX]\s+\d+\.\d+)[A-Z0-9-])+).*?(?=\s\d+\.\d+\s)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/iFmhRU/1). Replace with `$1`.

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                                 (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                                 (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                                 (1 or more times (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [xX]                     any character of: 'x', 'X'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                                 (1 or more times (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                                 (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                                 (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [A-Z0-9-]                any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '0' to
                               '9', '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```